# Javascript button onclick event not triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript file "functions.js" with the following:

```
function changeLabel() {
    alert("True");
}
```

a main javascript file server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(port);
});
```

and a html file with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="changeLabel()">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

and my json is

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  }
}
```

When looking at the network tab i have this:
[image]

But I do not manage to get the alert when clicking the button. I am pretty new to javascript coding...
Do I need to include my functions.js in the json file?

I am using visual studio 2019.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your http server doesn't have a path for `functions.js` so the browser's request for it fails and your js never loads. Look at the devtools network tab and see if it's erroring.

Comment: No error and it works if i do <button id="button" onclick="alert('True');">Click me</button>. Where is this devtools netzork tab?

Comment: @NicolasRey — https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: I see. I have changeLabel is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: You could also navigate the browser directly to `functions.js` and see if it loads, but the devtools might be slightly more informative.

Comment: Where in the dev tool do you see elements that load and those that do not?

Comment: @NicolasRey — Read ray's first comment again. They said to look at the Network tab to see if functions.js was loading. This has nothing to do with elements.

Comment: When your page loads, the browser sends _a separate request_ for `functions.js`. Your node server is only set up to serve `index.html` so the request for `functions.js` **_also returns the html, not the javascript._**

Comment: Okay, I just get what was the network tab. I started recording and I see localhost, functions.js, pageHook.js and page.js in status 200

Comment: I have included a screenshot of my network tab. @rayhatfield is there a way to include the functions.js then?

Comment: @NicolasRey See my updated comment above. Your server is always returning the html, even for the functions.js request. If you click the functions.js request in the network tab and view the response you'll see it's the html again.

Comment: Okay.. I am more a python coder, this is my first code in JS so I don't really know how to address the issue..

Comment: You just need to set up your server to [serve static files](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/) instead of always returning index.html. (That link appears to be very old and might be out of date, but the core concept hasn't changed.)

Comment: @NicolasRey - look at the blue box at the top of the page

Comment: @rayhatfield — Oooh, that's a useful bit of documentation. I'll add it to the duplicate.

Comment: It works!! Thanks guys!